# Newbie to Javascript: how to sum specific numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, console.log

Please help, I've been looking for an answer for far too long.
I'm trying to create an array using push method to insert the numbers
`0` to `10` into positions `0` through `10` of the numbers array you just initialized above.

I did this:

```
var numbers = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    numbers.push(i);
    console.log(numbers);
```

And got this result, which I think is correct but not 100% sure:

```
[ 0 ]
[ 0, 1 ]
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
0
```

Then I am to test the array push method by printing the sum of the values at 
position `3` and `6` of the array (use the `console.log()` function to print to the console). 
The outputted value should be `9`.

I am so stuck on this point and cannot find a sample anywhere of how to accomplish this.  I thought it might be something like:

```
console.log(numbers(sum[3, 6]);
```

Comment: Just add elements on position `3` and `6` together :) `console.log(numbers[3] + numbers[6])`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a sum() function, then try the following:

```
function sum(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}

console.log(sum(numbers[3], numbers[6]));
```

Here's a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7181h1ok/

Answer (score 0):

To sum the values of two indices of an array, you use the `+` addition operator in the following fashion:

```
var numbers = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ];
var sum = numbers[3] + numbers[6]; //adds the value in index 3 of the numbers array to the value in index 6 of the numbers array.
console.log(sum); //prints the sum to the console.
```

As a note, if you are unfamiliar with JavaScript and/or its operators, there's useful documentation at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) that can get you started.

Comment: Yes, I was on the w3shcols site.  Looked on many sites really and could not find a sample of what I was trying to accomplish.  How does the command change to sum all numbers in the array?

Comment: @AjaLee a function to sum all of the contents of an array would create a variable (for example, `out`) with a value of 0, then iterate through the array, adding each element to that previously created variable, and finally returning that variable.
It would look something like this:
`function sumArray(numArray) { var out = 0; for(var i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) { out += numArray[i] } return out; }`

Answer (score 0):

First, let's convert your code to a little bit better style:

```js
const numbers = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    numbers.push(i);
    console.log(numbers);
}
```

Note: I made `numbers` a `const` instead of a `var`, since you don't change it. I also made `i` a `let` binding instead of a `var`. In general, `var` is a legacy and should never be used. Use `const` instead if at all possible, otherwise use `let`.

Also, I inserted a space after the `for` keyword. It is generally recommended to separate the parentheses which enclose the header of a control structure keyword (`if`, `while`, `for`, etc.) with a space, to make it visually distinct from the parentheses for the argument list of a function call, which has no space.

Secondly: Your result is *not* correct. (Hint: how many numbers are the numbers 0 to 10?) It should include the numbers 0 to 10, but it only includes the numbers 0 to 9. You have what is generally called an *off-by-one-error*. These errors are very common when dealing with trying to manage loop indices manually. This is the fix:

```js
const numbers = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) { 
//                 ↑
    numbers.push(i);
    console.log(numbers);
}
```

Most modern programming languages have better alternatives than dealing with loop indices manually in the form of higher-level abstractions such as iterators, maps, and folds. Unfortunately, ECMAScript doesn't have a `Range` datatype, otherwise this could simply be expressed as converting a `Range` to an `Array`.

If ECMAScript *did* have a `Range` datatype, it *could* for example look like one of these:

```
const numbers = Range(0, 10).toArray()
const numbers = Array.from(Range(0, 10))
```

Here is an alternative for creating the `numbers` `Array` that doesn't involve manually managing loop indices, but still requires knowing that 0 to 10 are 11 numbers:

```js
const numbers = Array.from({length: 11}, (_, i) => i)
```

If you want to add the numbers at indices 3 and 6, you can simply dereference indices 3 and 6 and add the results:

```js
console.log(numbers[3] + numbers[6])
```

In the comments, you asked how you would add up all numbers in the `Array`. Combining the elements of a collection using a binary operator is called a `fold` or `reduce`, and [ECMAScript supports it out-of-the-box](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduce):

```js
console.log(numbers.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el));
```

Note how there is no explicit loop, thus no explicit management of loop indices. It is simply impossible to make an off-by-one-error here.

Answer (score -1):

It will be: `console.log((+numbers[3]) + (+numbers[6]));`

Typically, it should be `console.log(numbers[3] + numbers[6]);` but there's sometimes a issue that results in 36 instead of 9. The extra + signs tell javascript that it is a number.

NOTE: Remember that the first number is `numbers[0]`. The array starts with 0!

Comment: Thank you so much! My result is now : [ 0 ]
[ 0, 1 ]
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
9
0   So it looks like it worked?